# Is it possible to find as much matching words from different sentences located in different columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

There are sentences in column A and B.  I'm trying to find which sentences have the most matching words and return that sentence from column B.

```
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|Column A               |Column B               |Return most matched   |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|this is a black car    |Twinkle little star    |that is a black couch |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|there is a red cat     |London Bridge is Fallin|red cat is in the hat |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|I see a twinkle star   |red cat is in the hat  |Twinkle little star   | 
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
|London tower is standin|that is a black couch  |London Bridge is Fallin
+-----------------------+-----------------------+----------------------+
```

Beginner spreadsheet programmer here. Not sure if this is even possible?  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I've googled many that match single words but not match most matched words in sentences.

Comment: @player0, I've created a sheetview of the above. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

[link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W7Mwt4RVM-nLbOcJ82rt7FQC-GJMjqAJskH1c55LSJw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

paste in **C2** and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({B$2:B, MMULT(IFERROR(--REGEXMATCH(SPLIT(LOWER(B$2:B), " "), 
 "^"&SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(A2), " ", "$|^")&"$"), 0), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(SPLIT(B$2:B, " "))))^0)}, 
 "select Col1 order by Col2 desc limit 1", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: if you want it to be case sensitive you can remove all `LOWER`